# Typescript: Make public methods in parent become private/protected methods in derived class

Tags: typescript, oop, access-modifiers

I have this following class with some `public` methods:

```
class A {
  public methodOne() {}
  public methodTwo() {}
}
```

And I have a class that extends the above one.

```
class B extends A {}
```

How can I make the `methodOne` and `methodTwo` which are `public` in class `A` become `private` or `protected` in class `B`?

```
/*--- Expectation ---*/

const a = new A();
const b = new B();

a.methodOne(); //OK
b.methodOne(); //Error!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that, by design. It would make B exist in a limbo where it is claimed to be compatible with A (since it extends A), but also isn't compatible with A (since it doesn't have the same public properties as A).

The following function should be perfectly fine to write:

```
function doStuff(param: A) {
  param.methodOne();
}
```

But one of the benefits of subclassing is polymorphism. The doStuff function shouldn't need to worry whether it was passed something which is literally an A, or if it was instead passed something that extends from A. Typescript supports this, and so will treat both of the following lines as perfectly ok (if B extends from A):

```
doStuff(new A())
doStuff(new B())
```

For that to work, B has to have all the same properties as A. It might have more, but it can't have less.

If you don't want to have the same properties as A, then i recommend not extending from it.